# EXC_BREAKPOINT crash in iOS Extension when debug with some breakpoint

Tags: ios, crash, breakpoints, ios-extensions, unnotificationserviceextension

When I debug the code in iOS Extension. I face some crash with `EXC_BREAKPOINT` 
[image]

What did I do?

1. Run my APP with Xcode 11.5.
2. Start debugging for extension: `Debug` -> `Attach to Process by PID or name` -> `Input my Extension name and click Attach Button`
3. Setup some breakpoint in `Extension code` (Mine is `UNNotificationServiceExtension`)
4. Minimize the APP.
5. Push the notification.
6. Trigger the breakpoint which I set.
7. Continue to debug. Then I see this crash.

My question is how to debug extension in my case?

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bug from Xcode. I fix it by setting breakpoint at the SECOND time push notification.
So the steps are:

1. Run my APP with Xcode 11.5.
2. Start debugging for extension: `Debug` -> `Attach to Process by PID or name` -> `Input my Extension name and click Attach Button`
3. Minimize the APP.
4. Make sure there is no breakpoint in extension code.
5. Push the notification.
6. Setup some breakpoint in `Extension code` (Mine is `UNNotificationServiceExtension`)
7. Push the notification.
8. Trigger the breakpoint which I set.
9. Continue to debug. It works fine.